# Website Connection reset on XML upload

Tags: php, web-hosting, invision-power-board

I'm using a IP Board forum on my site, when I try to install a plugin to the forum (via a .xml file) my connection gets reset. I've tried installing the same forum on another server host and then it worked perfectly.

I've talked to my host about this and they tried disabling `MOD_SECURITY` and it didn't work, so they were 'convinced' it was something with the forum itself.

Now I'm asking this community to give me advice to what might cause this issue, so I can bring it to my host and ask them look into it.
It feels like it's some sort of upload limit for when you're on the actual website (not ftp). Maybe some php settings?

What do you think is the root cause of this issue?

Have any experience of "Connection reset"-errors?

Let me know! I'm in dire need of help since my current host doesn't really understand what causes this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several layers at which this could happen.
I would start by looking at the logs of the web server and php , then if needed I would tweak around some configurations of PHP and web server.

Some main settings relavent to the issue you are facing . 
php.ini settings :

- [post_max_size](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)
- [upload_max_filesize](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)
- [max_execution_time](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)
- [memory-limit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

Obviously there are several more things that can go wrong ( extensions gone rogue , etc )

Comment: I actually don't have a php.ini, though in cPanel I can change php version and set some php variables, gonna check if I can change those. Would it be better to create my own php.ini instead?

Comment: if your host allows it, you can modify those values using .htaccess also. or you should ask them to change it for you. Also do check the logs and try to find the real issue.

Comment: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/update-local-php-settings might be helpful

Comment: @Condolent haven't used cPanel in years , but I do belive there is an option to view logs .. Metrics > Errors.

Comment: I remembered that I changed some php settings before, but these look right to me so I don't think it's anything wrong with them https://gyazo.com/436461305a6a564d8d7922cdda6838b7